# Update is not a function mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to update a document using Mongoose.But keep getting the error Update is not a function...

I added an example from the Mongoose site and that does not work either.

```
var query = {firstName: "borne"};
Staff.update(query, { firstName: 'jason borne' }, null, function (err, numberAffected, raw) {}
```

My schema is as below which uses export so that i can pass in the Staff schema on the client side. The save works fine.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var StaffSchema = new Schema({
  firstName: String,
  surname: String,
  address: {addressLine1: String, addressLine2: String, town: String, county: String, postcode: String},
  telephoneNo: Number,
  mobileNo: Number,
  email: { type: String, lowercase: true },
  active: Boolean,

});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Staff', StaffSchema);
```

As stated the save works and below is the service i created

```
angular.module('xxx')
  .factory('staffActionService', function staffActionService ($location, $http, User, Staff, $cookieStore) {
    return {
      createStaff : function(staff, callback) {
        var cb = callback || angular.noop;
        return Staff.save(staff,
          function(data) {
            return cb(staff);
          },
          function(err) {
            return cb(err);
          }.bind(this)).$promise;
      },
      updateStaff: function(staff, callback) {
        var cb = callback || angular.noop;

        Staff.findOne({firstName: "borne"}, function (err, staff) {
          console.log(staff);


        });
```

I am using findOne to see if that would work but no joy. This final code is on the client side

The documentation is not too great.

Hope someone can assist

Comment: Have amended you can see it is passing the model into the service

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you are getting the specific error message, but your query seems to me slightly off. For example you are replacing your whole document here and on top of that you are passing needlessly a null value to the options.

Here's how I would write your query:

```
Staff.update({firstName: 'borne'}, {$set: {firstName: 'jason borne'}}, function (err, raw) {});
```